# How can I control the iterator value inside a for loop?

Tags: python

I would like to reproduce this JavaScript bucle in Python, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

```
for (i=0;i<toks.length && toks[i]!='\r'; i+=10)
```

Comment: I don't know what a "bucle" is, does it mean a piece of code which does not do anything?

Comment: The body of the loop is irrelevant. I only want to know how to control the index i in Python like I show in the question.

Comment: @JohnZwinck `bucle` is spanish for `loop` i assume.

Comment: see this [link](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops)  **syntax**:- for x in range(<start index>, <end index>, step function):  **example** :-  for x in range(3, 8, 2): -->output will be 3,5,7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure increment with 3rd argument of range and then check exit condition within the loop

```py
toks = list(range(100))
toks[30] = '\r'

for i in range(0, len(toks), 10):
    if toks[i] == '\r':
        break

    print(toks[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can write it using while

```
i = 0

while(i < len(toks) and toks[i] != '\r'):
    i += 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't like looping with indexes, so I suggest python `for` loop with `break` state (which stops the loop). Regarding every `10th` loop logic, you can have this using `toks[::10]`.

So the final code would be:

```py
for v in toks[::10]:
    if v == '\r':
        break
    print(v)
```

Comment: The idea is also interact with the 9 elements from toks[i] to toks[i+9], so I think this is not valid in this case. How could I access to those elements using this method?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add 10 to the iterator variable for each loop, you can simply do so by passing it as a parameter to the range function:

```
for i in range(0, MAX_ITERATIONS, 10):
    pass
```

The range function takes 3 parameters: the value to initialize the iterator variable, the maximum iterations and the value to add to the iterator variable for each loop (default is 1).

A code like that in python would be something like:

```
for i in range(0, len(toks), 10):
    if toks[i] == '\r':
        break
```